# Bug with installing ObjectAid into eclipse LUNA

Tags: eclipse, uml, objectaid

I have eclipse LUNA, and I am trying to install ObjectAid for building UML diagrams. When I try to install it I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Artifact osgi.bundle,org.junit,3.8.2.v3_8_2_v20100427-1100 is a folder but the repository is an archive or remote location.
```

Why do I get this error, and how to overcome it?

Thanks

Comment: I got this problem also when I tried to install GEF on my Eclipse. Maybe because I have an Eclipse IDE for Java Developers.

Comment: I am getting this problem also when I try to install e(fx)clipse on Eclipse modeling tools.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message during installing e(fx)clipse plugins. Also using Luna.

Following steps helped me:

1. Open the Eclipse Preferences and look for Install New Software
2. Add http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7 and try to install your plugin again.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. In this update location I can't find the update that I am searching for. When I try to get what I need I get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in ObjectAid 1.1.8. There was an issue with certain Eclipse distributions. They used some old JUnit bundles which were packaged different than expected by the installer.