# Error while installing e(fx)clipse plugin on Eclipe

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, efxclipse

I am trying to install e(fx) plugin on  Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 (Mac OS Yosemite).

I am following this steps:

> -> Help
>
> -> Install New Software...
>
> -> Click "Add.." button.
>
> -> As "name" type: e(fx)clipse and as "location" type: http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/1.2.0/site
>
> -> click "Ok".
>
> -> Select the plugin and install it as described at: http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html#for-the-ambitious

It begins downloading ... and at the some point, I get this error:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
> context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
> phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
> action=). No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.proxy,2.0.410.v201411191736 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee,1.1.802.v201501141657 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web,1.1.810.v201501141727 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core,1.2.701.v201501151629 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.standard.schemas,1.2.201.v201501151629 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.command.env.ui,1.1.200.v201501131952 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.core,1.1.802.v201501170605 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery,1.0.501.v201501132217 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui,1.3.301.v201501151629 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.xml.core,1.1.902.v201501151629 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,com.google.guava.source,15.0.0.v201403281430 No repository
> found containing: osgi.bundle,com.google.inject,3.0.0.v201312141243 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,com.google.inject.source,3.0.0.v201312141243 No repository
> found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.inject.source,1.0.0.v20091030 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.antlr.runtime,3.2.0.v201101311130 No repository found
> containing: osgi.bundle,org.antlr.runtime.source,3.2.0.v201101311130
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.cli,1.2.0.v201404270220 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.lang.source,2.6.0.v201404270220 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.apache.log4j.source,1.2.15.v201012070815 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common.source,2.10.1.v20140901-1043 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.source,2.10.1.v20140901-1043 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core,1.3.4.v201409021027 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils,1.3.4.v201409021027 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language,2.7.0.v201409021051 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.ui,2.7.0.v201409021051 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch,2.7.0.v201409021051 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.lib,2.7.0.v201409021027 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime,2.7.0.v201409021027 No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.web_core.feature,3.6.3.v201501151629
> No repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature,3.6.3.v201501151848
> No repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.server_ui.feature,3.3.402.v201501132217
> No repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.web_core.feature,3.6.3.v201501170605
> No repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature,3.6.3.v201501170605
> No repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.ws_ui.feature,3.7.0.v201501151848
> No repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_core.feature,3.6.3.v201501151848
> No repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature,3.6.3.v201501151848
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xpand,2.0.0.v201406030414 No repository found
> containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend,2.0.0.v201406030414 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.core,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.core.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.doc,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.examples,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.ide,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.ide.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.lib,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.lib.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.m2e,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtend.sdk,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.standalone,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.standalone.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend.typesystem.emf,2.0.0.v201406030414 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend2.lib,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtend2.lib.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository found
> containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.activities,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.activities.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.builder,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.builder.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.builder.standalone,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.builder.standalone.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.edit,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.edit.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.shared,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.shared.jdt38,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.shared.jdt38.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.shared.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.ui,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.ui.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.doc,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.doc.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtext.docs,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ecore,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ecore.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtext.examples,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtext.examples.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.generator,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.generator.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.junit,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.junit.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.junit4,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.junit4.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.logging,1.2.15.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.logging.source,1.2.15.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.m2e,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.purexbase,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.purexbase.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.purexbase.ui,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.purexbase.ui.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtext.runtime,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtext.runtime.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtext.sdk,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.smap,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.smap.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.codetemplates,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.codetemplates.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.codetemplates.ui,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.codetemplates.ui.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.ecore,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.ecore.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtext.ui,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.junit,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.junit.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtext.ui.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.util,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.util.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.xbase,2.7.2.v201409160908 No repository
> found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtext.xbase,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.junit,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.junit.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.ui,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.ui.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.examples,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.examples.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.graph,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.graph.source,2.7.2.v201409160908
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.source,2.7.2.v201409160908 No
> repository found containing:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.source,2.7.2.v201409160908

My Eclipe Luna 4.4.1 (Java EE Edition) is updated.

Comment: please also refer to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543061/bug-with-installing-objectaid-into-eclipse-luna/28194929#28194929

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issues when installing e(fx)clipse so I will provide a step-by-step installation guide which worked for me (under Windows). I have installed *e(fx)clipse 1.2.0* on *Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)* with *JDK 8u40*.

What did not work for me as well was using the (remote) update sites mentionend in the e(fx)clipse installation guide.

So here we go:

1. *Download fresh Eclipse* Luna SR2 (e.g. eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip)
2. unzip content -> now you have a folder "eclipse"
3. *Download XText runtime* ("http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/downloads/" -> "tmf-xtext-runtime-2.7.3.zip"). I used version 2.7.3. Extract zip-file to folder where your "eclipse"-folder is located. It should write its content to the 'features' and 'plugins' subfolders.
4. *Download e(fx)clipse update site assembly* ("http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/1.2.0/?d" -> site_assembly.zip) [note the '?d' at the end of the url to get directory listing]
5. *start eclipse* and select an empty dummy-workspace. maybe it works with an existing workspace as well, but just to be sure ...
6. *Add e(fx)clipse zip-archive as local repository* to eclipse: **Help -> Install New Software ... -> Add**. Name it as you want, e.g. 'e(fx)clipse [local]', press **Archive** and select *site_assembly.zip* archive downloaded. finally press ok to create repository.
7. Select "e(fx)clipse [local]" repository, check option "e(fx)clipse install", check "contact all update sites ..." and click next

The rest is just clicking *next* and *finish* on the following dialog pages. After a final restart e(fx)clipse works fine.

It should work under Linux or MacOS as well as it is an Eclipse issue.

I hope this guide is helpful.